# How do to update custom SPTimerjob?

Tags: timer-jobs, custom-timer-job

I have created & deployed a custom Jobdefinition via feature activation. During feature deactivation I use...

```
 Foreach(SPJobDefinition job in WebApp.JobDefinitions){
           If(job.Name.Contains("myJobName")){
                  job.Delete();
           }
  }
 WebApp.update()
```

I then checked with PoweShell and the definition was gone. I retract my solution.
Then in PowerspShell

```
 Restart-service sptimerv4
 Iisreset
 Restart-service sptimerv4
```

Re-deploy my solution/activate feature.  And again in PowerShell

```
  $tj = get-sptimerjob "myJobName"
   $tj.myMethod()
  >>Error no method found
```

Then I deployed the same build for the first time on another server & it worked great. How do I get the timerjob to properly update on the first server?

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to custom Timer jobs deployment, I always retract and remove deployed timer job first. Then restart `Windows Timer service` from `services.msc` and then add solution again to solution store using STSADM followed by STSADM deployment statement.

Now I wait for a while like few minutes and then run this command on all of WFEs to make sure solution is deployed,

```
stsadm -o execadmsvcjobs
```

[Source](http://sharepointbulletin.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/execute-timer-jobs-in-sharepoint-2007.html)

Once I am sure that solution is deployed, I activate the feature. I am not sure if it's best practice or not but it worked perfectly for me.

Back in days I used to simply use STSADM upgrade command but it didn't used to work efficiently for me and solution wasn't actually getting updated for some reason.